# Passing a number to an EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm working on an app to calculate forces for me. It works fine until I try to pass the final number value to a TextView. Here's the code (calc_Click being what is called when a button is clicked):

```
package com.hoodeddeath.physicscalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GravityActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gravity);
    }

    public void calc_Click(View v){
        double TEN = 10;
        double NEGELEVEN = -11;
        double G = 6.67*(Math.pow(TEN,NEGELEVEN));
        double TWO = 2;
        String mOneText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.massOne)).getText().toString();
        String aOneText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampOne)).getText().toString();
        String mTwoText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.massTwo)).getText().toString();
        String aTwoText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampTwo)).getText().toString();
        String distText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.distance)).getText().toString();
        String aThreeText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampThree)).getText().toString();

        double mOne = Double.parseDouble(mOneText);
        double aOne = Double.parseDouble(aOneText);
        double mTwo = Double.parseDouble(mTwoText);
        double aTwo = Double.parseDouble(aTwoText);
        double dist = Double.parseDouble(distText);
        double aThree = Double.parseDouble(aThreeText);

        mOne = mOne * aOne;
        mTwo = mTwo * aTwo;
        dist = dist * aThree;
        dist = Math.pow(dist, TWO);

        double total = (G * mOne * mTwo) / dist;

        TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalForceLabel);
        a.setText((int) total);
    }
}
```

Comment: and then what?  Some error?

Comment: What error do you get? Also learn to provide a [mcve]. It is simply a java problem, there is nothing to do with android.

Comment: Posting the error will help us find out exactly what happened. But at first glance, my guess would be that you didn't cast the object returned by findViewById to EditText. Try this: Double.parseDouble(((EditText)findViewById(...)).getText().toString)

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code:

```
    double mOne = Double.parseDouble(findViewById(R.id.finalForceLabel).toString());
    double aOne = Double.parseDouble(findViewById(R.id.ampOne).toString());
    double mTwo = Double.parseDouble(findViewById(R.id.massTwo).toString());
    double aTwo = Double.parseDouble(findViewById(R.id.ampTwo).toString());
    double dist = Double.parseDouble(findViewById(R.id.distance).toString());
    double aThree = Double.parseDouble(findViewById(R.id.ampThree).toString());
```

is incorrect. If you want to get the text of the edit texts, write this:

```
String someString = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampOne)).getText().toString();
```

And then parse it

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(someString);
```

**Why your code is wrong**:

Your code calls the method `findViewById` which returns a `View` object, not an `EditText`. And if you call `toString` on a `View`, it will return the memory address of the `View`, not the text of the view.

For this question in the comment:

> could you tell me why "TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalForceLabel); a.setText((int) total);" wouldn't work to pass the final number to a TextView?

This is because the `setText(int)` method accepts a resource id integer. So what is a resource id integer? In android, you might know that we can store different localizations of strings in different `strings.xml` files. And you can use the `Resources.getString(int)` method to get the string in the language of the android device. You will usually write:

```
 Resources r = this.getResources();
 r.getString(R.strings.someTextOrWhatever);
```

Where `R.strings.someTextOrWhatever` is an integer. The `setText` methods have an overload that takes a resource id. (Which is the one that you're using) If you pass a `1` to the method, it will not set the text to `1`, instead, it will look for the resource that corresponds to the id `1`. But there isn't a resource that corresponds to `1`! So that's why an exception is thrown.

What you should do is to pass a string instead of an integer.

```
a.setText(Double.toString(total));
```

This's just another one of those annoying Android methods. Sigh.

Comment: Thank you, but could you tell me why "TextView a = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finalForceLabel);
        a.setText((int) total);" wouldn't work to pass the final number to a TextView?